# What is the recommended approach to encrypt existing parameters?

Tags: aws-ssm

I have few hundreds, if not thousands, entries in the parameter store on one of my AWS accounts. At the moment they are just plain strings. I would like to encrypt them using the default KMS key but so far the only way I found to do this involves deleting the existing parameter. I also need to encrypt all the versions of existing parameters.

Is there a way to do this without deleting parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can update an existing String parameter to become a SecureString.

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name "test" --value "param" --type String
aws ssm put-parameter --name "test" --value "param" --type SecureString --overwrite
```

However, I don't think there is a way to edit the parameter version history to encrypt previous version values.

If it is unacceptable that the parameter history is unencrypted, I think you will need to write a script to delete each parameter and replace it with a SecureString parameter.